# GitHub Actions to EKS

Tags: maven, github-actions, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create a pipeline on github actions to EKS but Im having the following error on Build & Push Image step:

***------

> [2/2] ADD /target/customer.jar customer.jar:

---

Dockerfile:5
4 |
5 | >>> ADD /target/customer.jar customer.jar
6 |
7 |     ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=48m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"
error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount023157727/target: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount023157727/target: no such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.***

I think there is someething about context of the root step process because I can build the image locally with the same dockerFile (after building and creating the target folder of the project of course).

Any suggestion? What Am I missing?

**My DockerFile:**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre as release

ADD /target/customer.jar customer.jar

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=48m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar customer.jar" ]
```

**My Pipeline file:**

```
name: Release

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  RELEASE_REVISION: "pr-${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
  KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
  KUBE_NAMESPACE: default
  ECR_REPOSITORY: my-cool-application

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run:  mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.4.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@master

      - name: Docker cache layers
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-single-buildx-${{ github.sha }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-single-buildx

      - name: Build & Push Image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          RELEASE_IMAGE: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ env.RELEASE_REVISION }}
        run: |
          docker buildx create --use

          docker buildx build \
            --cache-from=type=local,src=/tmp/.buildx-cache \
            --cache-to=type=local,dest=/tmp/.buildx-cache-new \
            --tag ${{ env.RELEASE_IMAGE }} \
            --target release \
            --push \
            .

          rm -rf /tmp/.buildx-cache
          mv /tmp/.buildx-cache-new /tmp/.buildx-cache
      - name: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
        uses: kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master
        env:
          RELEASE_IMAGE: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ env.RELEASE_REVISION }}
        with:
          args: set image deployment/my-pod app=${{ env.RELEASE_IMAGE }} --record -n $KUBE_NAMESPACE
```